# How to push to git using gitPython with different users

Tags: python, git, push, gitpython

I use `gitPython` to push to a remote repo using different users who are logged in into our app.

For now I just push to repo like below:

```
logging.debug('Opening repo {}...'.format(repo_path))
repo = Repo(repo_path)
logging.debug('Repo is initialized :)')

logging.debug('git add: {} {}'.format(env, file_name))
repo.git.add(file_path)
commit_message = "Add new configs for {}".format(file_name)
logging.debug(commit_message)
repo.git.commit(commit_message)
repo.git.pull('origin', 'refs/heads/dev')
repo.git.push('origin', 'refs/heads/dev')
```

I have different users for git users in my ssh config if that helps:

```
Host user1
     HostName repo.remote.com
     User git
     Port 20022
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1

Host user2
     HostName repo.remote.com
     User git
     Port 20022
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

Now I want to push with specific users. Every user who is logged into our app has a different git user. Is it possible? How should solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you simply need to *not* use the remote `origin`, but instead the SSH URL

```
user1:path/to/repo
```

You need to build the remote url composed with:

- the username (which is conveniently the entry name in your ~/.ssh/config)
- the path to the repo in your remote Git repo hosting server.

So your `repo.git.push('origin', 'refs/heads/dev')` becomes:

```
repo.git.push('user1:path/to/repo', 'refs/heads/dev')
```

Comment: Note: the pull can still pull from origin.